# Google Colab Deforum Error in 'Python Definitions': FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory: './externals/Next_ViT/classification/nextvit.py'

Tags: python

Hello I'm new to google colab and am trying to run deforum (not locally). I've successfully installed Stable Diffusion and run it through google colab in the past, but am getting this error for the deforum notebook under the Python Definitions section.

[Deforum link I'm using](https://colab.research.google.com/github/deforum/stable-diffusion/blob/main/Deforum_Stable_Diffusion.ipynb#scrollTo=81qmVZbrm4uu)

**Error code**:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './externals/Next_ViT/classification/nextvit.py'
```

I've tried adding these lines to the environment setup as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74922342/step-4-in-my-deforum-stable-diffusion-notebook-keeps-giving-an-error-of-filenotf).

```
['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/isl-org/MiDaS.git'],
['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/bytedance/Next-ViT.git', 'externals/Next_ViT'],
```

But it didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a path problem in your code.

Go to the file `/content/MiDas/midas/backbones/next_vit.py` and edit the line

```
file = open("./externals/Next_ViT/classification/nextvit.py","r")
```

to

```
file = open("/content/MiDas/midas/backbones/vit.py","r")
```